# Sum(case when ..) for a distinct condition only

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following query:

```
select user_id, min(case when event='login' then date_trunc('day',time) end) first_login, 
max(case when event='login' then date_trunc('day',time) end) last_login, 
sum(case when event='login' then 1 end) sum_logins, 
sum(case when event='login' and date_trunc('day',time) between current_date and current_date-30 then 1 end) sum_logins_last_30 
from table
group by user_id
```

The issue here is that the sum is counting for every login even if multiple a day. What I am trying to get is total login count for unique days only (time is a timestamp and multiple logins can occur in one day), and trailing 30 day login count for unique days only.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Redshift, you might want to try two levels of aggregation:

```
select user_id,
       min(day_time) as first_login, 
       max(day_time) as last_login,
       sum(cnt) as num_logins, 
       sum(case when day_time between current_date - 30 and current_date then 1 else 0 end) sum_logins_last_30 
from (select user_id, date_trunc(day, time) as day_time, count(*) as cnt
      from table
      where event = 'login'
      group by user_id, date_trunc(day, time)
     ) t
group by user_id;
```

This sometimes works better than `count(distinct)`.

Also note other changes:

- This filters on `event = 'login'` in the `where` clause.  So, this version will not return users with no logins.
- `between` cares about the order of the 2nd and 3rd operands.  The "smaller" one should be first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count(distinct ..` and count the number of distinct days.

```
count(distinct case when event='login' and date_trunc('day',time) 
               between current_date-30  and current_date
               then date_trunc('day',time) end) sum_logins_last_30
```